# Remove Current Fragment and Launch Another Fragment from View Model

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

below is my ViewModel class which accepts application:Application as parameter.I want to launch another fragment from this class.But in remove() method,how do I pass fragment.

```
class EmailConfirmationFragmentViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
private lateinit var viewModelApplication: Application

init {

        this.viewModelApplication = application

}

var email = MutableLiveData<String>()
private var emailMutableLiveData: MutableLiveData<UserEmail>? = null
val userEmail: MutableLiveData<UserEmail>
    get() {
        if (emailMutableLiveData == null) {
            emailMutableLiveData = MutableLiveData<UserEmail>()
        }
        return emailMutableLiveData!!
    }

fun onEmailChanged(s: CharSequence, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {
    if (s.toString() != null && !s.toString().equals(""))
        email.value = s.toString()

}

fun onConfirmClicked(view: View) {

    userEmail.value = UserEmail(email.value.toString())
    launchResetPasswordFragment()

}

private fun launchResetPasswordFragment() {
    try {
        (viewModelApplication as FragmentActivity).supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.fl_Wrapper, OtpVerificationFragement()).remove(viewModelApplication.applicationContext).commit()
    }
    catch(e:Exception)
    {
        Log.e("Error","$e")
    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lifecycle events and Fragment transactions should never take place inside of a view model. As discussed in the [ViewModel Overview](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/viewmodel), a "ViewModel must never reference a view, Lifecycle, or any class that may hold a reference to the activity context." While the `AndroidViewModel` does introduce an anti-pattern by exposing a reference to the application, this specific use case is not an appropriate one. In situations where the view model should invoke a fragment transaction, it's most commonly handled by the general concept of an event dispatched from the view model to the Lifecycle Owner. I believe employing such a pattern can resolve your issue. While I don't know the state of your Fragment, I've devised a likely solution.

```
class EmailConfirmationViewModel() : ViewModel() {

    val email: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

    private val _resetFragment: MutableLiveData<Event> = MutableLiveData()
    val resetFragment: LiveData<Event> = _resetFragment

    val userEmail: UserEmail?
        get() = email.value?.let { UserEmail(it) }

    fun onEmailChanged(s: CharSequence) {
        email.value = s.toString()
    }

    fun onConfirmClicked() {
        resetFragment()
    }

    private fun resetFragment() {
        _resetFragment.value = Event()
    }
}
```

Where the supporting event classes could appear as such:

```
class Event : EventWithValue<Unit>(Unit)
```

```
open class EventWithValue<T>(
    private val value: T,
) {

    private var isHandled = false

    fun getValueIfUnhandled(): T? = if (isHandled) {
        null
    } else {
        handleValue()
    }

    private fun handleValue(): T {
        isHandled = true
        return value
    }
}
```

```
class EventObserver<T>(
    private val eventIfUnhandled: (value: T) -> Unit,
) : Observer<EventWithValue<T>?> {

    override fun onChanged(event: EventWithValue<T>?) {
        event?.getValueIfUnhandled()?.let { eventIfUnhandled(it) }
    }
}
```

Through observing the event in the Fragment itself, you eliminate the need to reference any sort of view in the view model while maintaining the view model's role as the dispatcher. Here's a brief description of how you would listen to the event from your Lifecycle Owner, in this case, a Fragment.

```
class EmailConfirmationFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
            inflater: LayoutInflater,
            container: ViewGroup?,
            savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val view: View? = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
        val viewModel: EmailConfirmationViewModel by viewModels()

        viewModel.resetFragment.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, EventObsever {
            // Call a function of the activity's viewModel (ideal), or complete the transaction here through referencing the activity directly (ill-advised)
        })

        return view
    }
}
```

I think exposing `userEmail` is a bit of a code smell in itself. Alternatively, you could define the `resetFragment` event as

```
private val _resetFragment: MutableLiveData<EventWithValue<UserEmail>> = MutableLiveData()
val resetFragment: LiveData<EventWithValue<UserEmail>> = _resetFragment
```

and receive the value of the `userEmail` directly within the event listener featured above. This would remove the need to expose the `userEmail` of the view model.